# Configurações PHP necessárias para servidor local

Tags: php, servidor

Estou começando o desenvolvimento em PHP, e já comecei a ter algumas incompatibilidades em meus códigos. Digo em questão de algo funcionar localmente e quando faço upload pro servidor, algo dá errado.

No servidor, a versão do PHP é:

```
PHP Version 5.2.17
```

Localmente, a versão do PHP é:

```
PHP Version 5.5.7
```

Gostaria de saber as melhores recomendações para se evitar incompatibilidades nos códigos quando executados localmente e quando executados no servidor, tirando a versão do php, porque sei que é essencial ter a mesma versão em ambos. Configurações necessárias do php.ini e etc.

Um problema que me deparei ultimamente me deu muita dor de cabeça (descobri que era simples após fazer um questionamento aqui no fórum e descobrir o que causava o erro), simplesmente meu `PHP` local não gerava erro quando uma função `header();` era chamada após algum código `html`, ou o arquivo vinha configurado com codificação `UTF8 com BOM`.

Mesmo o `error_reporting = E_ALL` estando habilitado dessa maneira (não sei se tem algo a ver com esse tipo de erro), o erro não foi mostrado. Então o que quero saber são as configurações necessárias que vão deixar o servidor local o mais "próximo" possível de um servidor dedicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente equalizar a versão e os módulos ativos, poucas coisas no php.ini vão gerar incompatibilidades de código.

Use a função [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) ela retorna todas as configurações e módulos ativados, basta executar nos dois, comparar e configurar o servidor local da mesma forma do remoto.

Outra dica é ver no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) as modificações de uma versão para a outra, para saber com mais exatidão o que não poderá usar.

Ah, verifique também a versão do servidor MySQL, pois poderá ter problemas com querys incompatíveis.

Answer (score 0):

Usa [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), assim tu podes ter o mesmo ambiente de produção na tua máquina de desenvolvimento, inclusive podes ter vários ambientes configurados.
Se tu usas Windows, [aqui](http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-o-vagrant-como-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-no-windows) tem um bom tutorial, tem um [livro](https://leanpub.com/vagrantcookbook-ptbr) muito bom também.